# Open a PowerShell script in VBA with environment variable

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I am trying to run a VBA macro to run a PowerShell script.  I can get the script to work by putting the full path of the current user profile after the `-File` parameter.

However, I need the script to work for all users.

I tried `$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\open\file_merge.ps1`, but that didn't find the directory.  So, I went to below but I am getting a syntax error.  Can anyone assist?

```vb
Dim retval

retval = Shell("powershell -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File ""Environ("USERPROFILE")" & "\Desktop\open\file_merge.ps1""", 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$env:USERPROFILE` only works from within PowerShell, so you can't use it in a commandline started from somewhere else.

Your `Shell` statement doesn't work, because your quoting is broken, and VBA (like other VB dialects) doesn't expand expressions or variables inside strings. Use string concatenation to work around this issue:

```vb
retval = Shell("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File """ & _
         Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\open\file_merge.ps1""", 1)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can use environment variables directly:

```vb
retval = Shell("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\open\file_merge.ps1""", 1)
```

but it would work if you prepended the commandline with `cmd /c`:

```vb
retval = Shell("cmd /c powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\open\file_merge.ps1""", 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, Ansgar!  I really appreciate the explanation.  You learn something new every day and you helped immensely   I used the string concatenation example.

Answer (score -1):

Not the last foulup in there but

```
""Environ("USERPROFILE")" &
```

seems to be missing some ampersands if you want to pass the environ USERPROFILE to Powershell